# Transaction problem with JPA2-spring-Hibernate

Tags: spring

Hi I got a problem with the above integration of the frameworks.

I'm using JPA2 in a maven configuration with the library versions:

- Spring 3.0.5
- Hibernate 3.5.4
- Hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final

I'm using the persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="AccountingPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.domain.BaseEntity</class>
        <class>com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.domain.AccountSettings</class>
        <!-- This is not any more necessary, it will be done in spring config.
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        </properties> -->
    </persistence-unit>
```

and the applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.service" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" 
    proxy-target-class="false"
    mode="proxy" />

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    p:driverClassName="${dataSource.driverClassName}" p:url="${dataSource.url}"
    p:username="${dataSource.username}" p:password="${dataSource.password}" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:datasource.properties" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
```

The class AccountSettingsDaoImpl is annotated with @Repository.
The methods for database access in this class are marked with @Transactional:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public void save(E entity) {
//      entityManager.merge(entity);
//      entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }
```

The Test class is the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
public class AccountSettingsDaoImplTest {

    @Resource
    private AccountSettingsDaoImpl accountSettingsDaoImpl;

    private final static Long id=1L;

    @Test
    public void testSave() throws Exception {
        AccountSettings accountSettings = new AccountSettings();
        accountSettings.setCategory("A");
        accountSettings.setDescription("adlkjsadhad asdlkasdkjahsdlkashd ");
        accountSettingsDaoImpl.save(accountSettings);

        Long localId = accountSettings.getId();
        System.out.println("id="+localId);
    }
}
```

But running my JUnit-Tests, I will get the following exception:

```
29.07.2011 18:46:01 org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SCHWERWIEGEND: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@127e942f] to prepare test instance [com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.dao.AccountSettingsDaoImplTest@6b9c18ae]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.dao.AccountSettingsDaoImplTest': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'accountSettingsDaoImpl' must be of type [com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.dao.AccountSettingsDaoImpl], but was actually of type [$Proxy23]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:220)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:301)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:303)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'accountSettingsDaoImpl' must be of type [com.westernacher.wps.bnotk.fibu.dao.AccountSettingsDaoImpl], but was actually of type [$Proxy23]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:409)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297)
    ... 26 more
29.07.2011 18:46:01 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext doClose
```

Can anyone help me?

Best Regards, Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't inject proxies by concrete type (if they are made by interface) - you should use the interface instead:

```
@Inject
private AccountSettingsDao accountSettingsDao;
```

Comment: wow, that tip was wonderful and so fast. That made it working. Thanks a lot.